# Joomla drop down menu going behind other modules

Tags: javascript, joomla

I am using a drop down menu on my site, and the sub-menu is dropping behind the page content on hover - http://volotechdev.com/nant/

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some relevant code (and maybe a JSFiddle example) here. With only an external link, the question will have no value to future readers once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things try adding a z-index:20 to your menu and also try adding this param to your flash

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

and also can try adding the following parameter to the EMBED tag:

```
wmode="transparent"
```

Comment: Tried those options earlier, no luck.  I just went ahead with a different menu system.  Thank though :-)